# How to resolve inconsistence between runtime model & runtime-independent representation

Tags: architecture, software-design

I am beginner in software analysis & design.

[This is my abstract design.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJvLu.png) Its purpose is providing user experience of utterance from textual sentence.

Microsoft Synthesis is a component of target runtimes & its function is transform text to audio. It provides JS API in MS Edge.

In my runtime-independent model, text is firstly transformed into utterance which I defines as entity holding address to audio data. Then the utterance is messaged to audio interface which plays the audio from the address.

Unconformability happened when I tried to convert my abstract model to the runtime-dependent representation

I recognized an inconsistence that MsS holds two responsibilities which are separated in my abstract model into ***sentence2utterance service*** & ***audio interface***.

Are there problems in my design decision making, perception, or underlying assumptions?

If not how to resolve the inconsistence to derive from abstract model a runtime-dependent model with MS Synthesis as a component runtime?

I expect primarily identification of potential faults in my software design brain from external clear mind then a solution to the inconsistence.

Could you offer me insights into the faults or solution to the inconsistence?